# problem on onclick() event for more than one clicks done on a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an html page where,when hovered over the first image a second image fades in/is shown.The first image has an `onclick()` event which performs a transition of rotating the image and scaling it by some number.During the transition, the first image disappears and some text appears on the same place(area of the div tag of the first image).I perform the transition through javascript and the hovering animation using css. Now when i click on the text(or the area of the div tag) the transition must reverse back i.e., the div area must be as it was before clicking(even with the hovering working.). I would like to know the answer through pure javascript please.
Thank you in advance.

```js
timesclicked = 0;
document.getElementById("hoverImage").addEventListener("click", function() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById('container');
    timesclicked+=1;
    if(timesclicked%2!=0)
    { 
        //obj.style.opacity = '0.5';
        x.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-360deg) scale(1.4)';
        x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
        setTimeout(() => {
            x.innerHTML = '<div style="font-size:16px; font-family: monospace; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; "> My Hero Academia, abbreviated as HeroAca is a Japanese superhero manga series written and illustrated by Kōhei Horikoshi. It has been serialized in Weekly Shōnen Jump since July 2014, and, as of February 2019, 22 volumes have been collected in tankōbon format.</div>'},'1300');
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-45deg) scale(1)';
        x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
        setTimeout(() => {
            x.innerHTML = '<img src="https://picsum.photos/300">'},'500');
    }
});
```

```css
img
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#mainImage,#hoverImage 
{
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

#hoverImage
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.1s ;
}

#hoverImage:hover 
{
    opacity: 1; 
}

#container
{
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/300);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:40%;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
#container:before
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
    <img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
    <img id="hoverImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
</div>
```

As much as i know, I think the second clicking event is not happening because the eventlistener is on the hoverImage. I need a way to run the else part of the code somehow.

Comment: I believe you might find helpful this: `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the click event listener on the container div.

```js
timesclicked = 0;
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById('container');
    timesclicked+=1;
    if(timesclicked%2!=0)
    { 
        //obj.style.opacity = '0.5';
        x.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-360deg) scale(1.4)';
        x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
        setTimeout(() => {
            x.innerHTML = '<div style="font-size:16px; font-family: monospace; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; "> My Hero Academia, abbreviated as HeroAca is a Japanese superhero manga series written and illustrated by Kōhei Horikoshi. It has been serialized in Weekly Shōnen Jump since July 2014, and, as of February 2019, 22 volumes have been collected in tankōbon format.</div>'},'1300');
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.transform = 'rotateZ(-45deg) scale(1)';
        x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
        setTimeout(() => {
            x.innerHTML = '<img src="https://picsum.photos/300">'},'500');
    }
});
```

```css
img
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#mainImage,#hoverImage 
{
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

#hoverImage
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s 0.1s ;
}

#hoverImage:hover 
{
    opacity: 1; 
}

#container
{
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/300);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:40%;
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
#container:before
{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
   <img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
   <img id="hoverImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
</div>
 
</style>
```

Comment: but the hover image is not working. I want the to work too

Comment: hey it works fine for my code but after the second click the hover doesn't work what to do?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are a few problems with your code, and you're going to have some debugging to do. That said, try this for a strategy:

- Put your on-click event on the `#container`.
- Put *all* the styling and transitioning details in the css. Your javascript will just add and remove a class from the `#container`.
- Don't track the number of clicks unless you need it for something else. Have your if statement check for the presence or absence of the class you're toggling. (Or use an explicit [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead of an if-else block.)
- Don't add and remove the text and background in the javascript, put them both in the HTML and control their visibility using the CSS.

### edit:

People asked for examples and clarification. I'm stealing some of this from other people's answers.
I'm not completely sure I've understood OP's intentions correctly, and there are some rough-around-the-edgues details (like the cursor when you hover before clicking), but I think this should serve as an example:

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("click", function(){
    container.classList.toggle("selected");
  });
```

```css
#mainImage, #hoverImage, #selectedText {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
#hoverImage {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.1s;
}
#container:hover > #hoverImage {
  opacity: 1; 
}
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:40%;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
#container.selected {
  transform: rotateZ(-360deg) scale(1.4);
}
#container:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
#selectedText {
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/300?text);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s 0.5s;
}
#container.selected > #selectedText {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.1s 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="mainImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300?main">
  <img id="hoverImage" src="https://picsum.photos/300?hover">
  <div id="selectedText">
    My Hero Academia, abbreviated as HeroAca is a Japanese superhero
    manga series written and illustrated by Kōhei Horikoshi. It has been
    serialized in Weekly Shōnen Jump since July 2014, and, as of
    February 2019, 22 volumes have been collected in tankōbon format.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be an even better answer if you gave examples.

Comment: but i don' t know a way to do the .innerhtml thing without using javascript.Can u help on that?

Comment: and i also want the transitions to happen onclick i can't do that using css,right?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem correctly, I think you just need to move the transition styles into your CSS

```
x.style.transition = 'all 1.5s ease-in-out';
```